# Unable to restore `AVAssetDownloadTask` after app relaunches

Tags: ios, download, http-live-streaming

I'm downloading some HLS streams and everything goes well unless I kill the app.

When the app restart, recreating `AVAssetDownloadURLSession` should restart all ongoing tasks, as explained in https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/504/ (around 20:40)

But it doesn't. Or at least it doesn't informs the delegate.

When i relaunch the app, I call `session.getAllTasks`, but it often returns 0 running task.

And when it return the downloading task, the `AVAssetDownloadDelegate` is never called on progress. I don't even know if the download is still going!

According to the video, implementing backgrond download should be simple. But I cannot figure out how to restore download tasks reliably?

Comment: Hey Martin, we have the same issue. Did you solve it?

Comment: Still not, but since the download continue when the app is in background, this case won't occur very often. I need restore only if the user or the system kills the app.
And it would be counter productive for a user to kill an app which is downloading something. So this case is not so frequent.